# Transforming a numpy array into another

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `numpy` array with elements of data type `numpy.dtype("i8,i8,f4")`.

I would like another array that keeps just the two integers of each element, i.e. `numpy.dtype("i8,i8")`.

Is there an easier/cleaner way to achieve this than a for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't actually named the columns, they are normally called f0,f1...; and you can use indexing to access them. I believe this is what you are after:

```
x[['f0','f1']]
```